# Use Domain from Google Mail for Business

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, domain

A friend started to use "Google Apps for Business" (Mail) where he has to pay for it. He also registered **through Google** a Domain with his name (office@namename.com)

When he now enters the domain `www.namename.com` a Google page says that this domain does not exist (quite logical).

He asked me how he can setup a homepage, but I'm don't know how this "Google Apps for Business" thing works.

Is it possible to point the domain to a shared web hosting server, in order to generate a website for him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend have at least three ways for publish a website with Google apps:

- If he bought the domain through Google apps also has a control panel on GoDaddy. From them can point a subdomain everywhere
- He can activate 'Sites' directly from Google apps.
- Create an app on Google App Engine

..is flexible enough.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i got his credentials in order to have a look at the admin board from google. but how can i log into godaddy? are you sure i also got a control panel from godaddy when i buy the domain via google? **EDIT** ah i think i found something. under "more settings" -> "domains" -> "redirect naked domain" i can redirect it to another webspace :) ... and under "change DNS settings" i will be redirected to the domainhoster (but in the case from my friend it is domaindiscount24.com, not godaddy, but doesn't matter). thanks